# Tiered Discount Price calculation Google Sheets formula

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a pricing subtotal based on tiered discount.
I found various examples online for Excel but was not able to grok it and make it work in Google Sheets.

What I'm trying to do is calculate the subtotal for 2 line items based on the green and yellow discount tables:

[image: Image of my sheet]

This would be a correct calculation for 40 site licenses:

20 * 150 + 10 * 120 + 10 * 90 = 5100

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1leBPGJ4HZf9t3ac0SrS3-UIfbbjU43Qo-ft5dDkv_wM/edit?usp=sharing

I added 2 examples calcs in the blue box at the bottom. thx.

Comment: Thanks again for your help but I noticed there is a bug in the formula. If the Item Count value is equal to one of the tier stop values, it will give a wrong number. Trying entering 29 and then 30 in the Item Count column and you'll see what I mean. I had some other people look at it but unfortunately none were able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM({QUERY(({0; I$6:I$12}-I$6:I$13)*-1, 
 "limit "&MATCH(VLOOKUP(C6, H$6:H$12, 1, 1), H$6:H$12, 0)-1); 
 C6-VLOOKUP(C6, I$6:I$12, 1, 1)}*
 INDIRECT("J6:J"&MATCH(VLOOKUP(C6, H$6:H$12, 1, 1), H$6:H$12, 0)+ROW(H$6)-1)))
```

[image: 0]

### [spreadsheet demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17-BNA39Y6mp4Ezs1ba9MN3ziXgb6keEvowa-ridtH_E/edit#gid=0)

Comment: thx, it seems to work well. Except when I put a "count" below 20, then it will bug out. is that something we can fix?

Comment: sure, see D9 in demo sheet

Answer (score 0):

The classic approach to this would be

```
=SUMPRODUCT((C26>H$6:H$12)*(C26-H$6:H$12+1)*(J$6:J$12-n(J$5:J$11)))
```

[Adapted from](http://www.mcgimpsey.com/excel/variablerate.html)

[image]